# How to fill in missing days of data with average of day before and after

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets, google-colaboratory, looker-studio

I got **Amazon Stock data from Yahoo finances**, but there are some missing days that have no data.

I was wondering if there was a way, using **google collab**, to then "create" those missing days and fill them in with the average of whatever the adjacent days are.

I want to use the closest days with data, before and after the **missing days**, to create data for the missing days.

I have looked at many answers of slack, but I can't find a specific answer to my solution. The command that seems the closest is: 
    `ws = Amazon.worksheet('Amazon')
     idx = pd.date_range(start = '05-15-1997', end = '07-05-2019')
     Amazon_df = get_as_dataframe(ws)
     AMZ = pd.DataFrame(Amazon_df)
     AMZ.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(AMZ.index)
     AMZ = AMZ.reindex(idx, fill_value=np.nan)`

The problem with this command is that I will have to manually add the missing days and with Amazon stock, this will take a really long time.

I can't seem to figure out how to solve this problem. A link to the spreadsheet is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fLicjjVRTchd8ps6aiVsGfP1GVFfvJN2rgfoYxxSHZk/edit?usp=sharing

I want to figure out this data so I will be able to graph is without random 'missing' days. I would like to fill the "missing" days with the average values of the days before and after, that actually have data.

Comment: You should extract a few data from the full dataset with missing days, and explain **and** show how you would like to fill missing values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use simulation for fill missing values. I have a function `rts_clean()` but in R code (`GeoRTS` package), it's based on the STL-loess decomposition (trend, stationality and noise, that admit missing values), first decompose the time series in those 3 components, then you just simulate the values for noise using it's distribution (for available data). Then you obtain somthing like this:

Example:
https://github.com/InstitutoInvestigacionesEconomicasPUCE/geortsBeta/blob/master/man/figures/rearme_img1.png

Code: 
https://github.com/InstitutoInvestigacionesEconomicasPUCE/geortsBeta/blob/master/R/rts_clean.R

Comment: is there a way to do this in colab

Comment: also, why does my reindex function remove all data provided?

Comment: is there a way for you to write the code to a generic data frame?